# View AWS CLI export for an AWS EMR cluster, terminated several months ago

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

So I have the following problem.
Several months ago I was working on an AWS EMR cluster and I created a specific configuration and steps for it.
After that, I saved the AWS CLI export and terminated the cluster.
Sadly, there were a problem with my PC and now the file with the CLI script is gone.
I checked the EMR cluster list in AWS, but the terminated instance is not there, because 2 weeks have passed since it was terminated.

Is there a way to retrieve the old terminated instances or at least get the CLI script?
I have instance logs in S3, but there are logs for 70 instances and I don't know the ID of the latest instance.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the metadata for the logs in S3, you should be able to determine which of the 70 is the most recent by S3 key creationTime. "aws s3 ls ..." prints out the creationTime for each key it lists.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had the same idea, the problem was that there is no last modified date or created date for a folder in S3, so I had to go in 2-3 levels of folders in order to find a file and check the date. I was trying to find a solution without doing it, but sadly there were no other solution. So after 30 min of searching I found what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is because there is not actually a concept of folders in S3; rather, the CLI is simply splitting on '/' when listing the objects for you.

Comment: I should have told you to use "aws s3 ls --recursive ...". Sorry you had to spend so much time!